# PHP: how to retrieve the filename of the file contained in .gz?

Tags: php, gzip

My test.gz contains for instance : image1.jpg.

How can I decompress the test.gz so it gives me image1.jpg ?

I tried that method:

```
$file = gzopen($file_name, 'rb');
$out_file = fopen($out_file_name, 'wb');
```

but it supposes you need to know the filename contained in the .gz file

regards

Comment: GZip typically does not save the original filename (or any metadata), `.gz` is just an extension to indicate that the file has been compressed with GZip. If you want to save filenames along with your compressed data, you're going to have to use an additional layer, like `tar` or come up with your own data format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use PHP [PharData](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php) to extract and read its content.

To extract `tar` or `tar.gz` :

```
    $phar = new PharData('myphar.tar');
    $phar->extractTo('/full/path');
```

And to list all files, you can use :

```
archive = new PharData('/upload/directory/myphar.tar.gz');

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($archive) as $file) {
    echo $file . "<br />";
}
```